# Does anyone know how to issue a SUBMIT command to OpenVMS over an FTP session?

Tags: ftp, telnet, openvms

I am currently using windows telnet to submit files to the OpenVMS queue via a series of sendkeys/application waits through VBA.  It works, up until the end-user shifts focus away from the telnet window.  I would prefer to issue the SUBMITs using an FTP session, where I can script the commands into a batch file and shoot it across FTP.  I was able to do something similar with IBM mainframes - through the quote site FTP command - setting the filetype=jes, followed by a JCL file that would be dropped into the work queue for immediate execution.  I can't seem to find anything on the internet related to FTP, openVMS, and submit.  I have tried using Quote submit/que=... but it does not recognize the command.  (Submit works fine under telnet).

Comment: You can't use FTP to send directly to a batch queue. You could run a batch job or detached process that periodically checks a directory for new files. When one it appears it can submit it to the appropriate batch queue. With a little extra work it could email the log file.

Comment: If available on both sides, use can use ssh to execute a command on a remote node: you probably want to set -o BatchMode. And, you can use public key authentication.

Comment: I like Hartmutt's suggestion of a periodic check (from a batch job :-). I would discourage just submitting a new found file for obvious security reasons. If at all possible I would submit a known batch scripts when a fresh data file  shows up: .CSV, .TXT, fresh source file like a .COB. Select processing script based on file name and type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Remote Shell Protocol (RSH) to execute a command in a remote node
You would need a rsh client on windows:
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rsh.mspx?mfr=true

And also enable RSH service on VMS via TCPIP$CONFIG 
(See OpenVMS documentation http://h71000.www7.hp.com/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This works best with a VMS username dedicated to processing inbound FTP files. If you put in the LOGIN.COM for that username to detect it's a network connection and submit a batch job to look for the expected file, get exclusive access to it with retries (the FTP is done), and then process the file - That has worked for me.

The other option is to put a security ACL on the directory and make an audit listener - it will get file creates via a mailbox message. Then it can do similar: get exclusive access to the file being created and then process it.